# Let $X=\{f\in C[0,1] :f(0)=0 \}$. Prove that there does not exist $f\in X$ such that $\|f \|_{\infty}\leq 1$ and $|T(f)|= 1$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X=\{f\in C[0,1] :f(0)=0 \}$. Prove that there does not exist $f\in X$ such that $\|f \|_{\infty}\leq 1$ and $|T(f) |= 1$. Define
\begin{align}T:X&\to \Bbb{R}\\&f\mapsto T(f)=\int^{1}_{0}f(t)dt\end{align}

**My trial**

Suppose for contradiction that there exists $f\in X$ such that $\|f \|_{\infty}\leq 1$ and $|T(f) |= 1$. Then,

$$1=|T(f) |\leq \sup\limits_{\|f \|\leq 1}|T(f) |=\|T(f) \|.$$

I'm stuck here, I don't see how to get a contradiction. Kindly help.

Comment: What does $T_f$ mean?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: I'll edit.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: I've edited it. Thanks!

Comment: The information $|T(f)| = 1$ and $|f(x)| \le 1 \, \forall x$ together imply that $f(x)$ is either constant $1$ or constant $-1$. This is a problem.

Comment: @T. Bongers: Problem as how? Can you explain?

Comment: Spend some time thinking about it. Is $f(x)$ constant $1$ or constant $-1$? Do you have some information to preclude this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\in X$.

You have $f(0) = 0$. By using the continuity of $f$, let $r>0$ be such that for all $x\in [0, r]$, $|f(x)|\le \frac{1}{2}$. Then using the fact that $|f(x)| \le 1$ for all x :

$$ |T(f)| = \left|\int_0^1 f \right| \le \int_0^1 |f(t)|dt = \int_0^r |f(t)|dt + \int_r^1 |f(t)|dt \le \frac{r}{2} + 1-r = 1 - \frac{r}{2}<1$$

Comment: Hello, I showed that if $f\in X$ and $||f||_{\infty}$ then $|T(f)| < 1$. Which shows the result you want. You can convince yourself that it is true by using contradiction : Let $f\in X$  such that $||f||_{\infty} \le 1$ and $|T(f)| = 1$. Then because $||f||_{\infty}\le 1$, we have $T(f) < 1$ so that $1< 1$ : contradiction.

Comment: That's fine! Let me go through the proof. Then, I'll get back to you!