# Banach space - using continuity to show contradiction

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $X=(C[-1,1], \| \cdot \|_\infty)$. Let $Y=\{f \in C[-1,1] : \int_{-1}^0 f = \int_0^1 f \}$ be a subspace.

Let $\phi(f)= \int_{-1}^0 f -\int_0^1 f $.

Then we have $Y=Ker(\phi)= \phi^{-1}\{0 \}$.

Suppose there exists $v \in x$ with $\| v\|_{\infty}=1$ such that $\phi(v)= \| \phi\|$. Then I want to show that this is a contradiction.

I tried to show the contradiction by using that $\phi$ is continuous.

i.e. I used a similar argument as [Let $X=\{f\in C[0,1] :f(0)=0 \}$. Prove that there does not exist $f\in X$ such that $\|f \|_{\infty}\leq 1$ and $|T(f)|= 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125322/let-x-f-in-c0-1-f0-0-prove-that-there-does-not-exist-f-in-x-such?rq=1), by taking $r>0$. Then I get $0 = | \phi(t)| <2 -3r$, which didn't get anywhere.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $f$ one has
$$
  |\phi(f)| \leq
  \left|\int_{-1}^0f(x)\,  dx\right| +   \left|\int_0^1f(x)\,  dx|\right| \leq  \|f\| + \|f\| = 2 \|f\|,
  $$
so $\|\phi\|\leq 2$.  Letting
$$
  f_n(x) = \left\{\matrix{
  1, & \text {if }  -1\leq x<-1/n,\hfill \cr
  -nx, & \text {if } -1/n\leq x\leq 1/n, \cr
  -1, & \text {if }  \phantom{- \ } 1/n\leq x\leq 1,\hfill \cr
  }\right.
  $$
we have $\|f_n\|=1$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty }\phi(f_n)=2$, so actually  $\|\phi\|=2$.

Given $f$ in $C[-1, 1]$ with   $\|f\|=1$, let
$$
  A=\int_{-1}^0f(x)\,  dx, \quad \text{and}\quad   B=\int_0^1f(x)\,  dx.
  $$
Observing that $-1\leq A,B\leq 1$, the only way one can get $\phi(f)=2$, that is,
$A-B=2$, is when $A=1$ and $B=-1$. In this case we have
$$
  0 = 1-A = \int_{-1}^0\,  dx - \int_{-1}^0f(x)\,  dx
  = \int_{-1}^0\, 1-f(x)\,  dx.
  $$
Since $1-f(x)$ is continuous and nonnegative, this implies that $f(x)=1$ on $[-1,0]$.  In a similar way it follows
that $f(x)=-1$ on $[0, 1]$, but this violates the continuity of $f$.  Therefore you never get $\phi(f)=2$.

Comment: I think that you need to switch $1$ with $-1$ in your definition of $f_n$, otherwise you get $\phi=-2$. But the proof is beautiful!